# MATLAB one liner for batch assignment in 2D matrix?

Tags: matlab

Say I have a matrix

```
A = zeros(5, 5);
```

Instead of looping with a for loop, I wish to batch-modify some of the elements. For example, I wish to change elements marked by `pts_to_modify` to 1, where

```
pts_to_modify=[[2 3]; [3 2]];
```

So I wish `A` to become

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

However, when I do

```
A(pts_to_modify(:, 1), pts_to_modify(:, 2)) = 1,
```

I get

```
A =

     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     1     0     0
     0     1     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
```

How can I do it correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sub2ind`:

```
>> ind = sub2ind(size(A), pts_to_modify(1,:), pts_to_modify(2,:))
ind =
    12     8
>> A(ind) = 1
A =
      0     0     0     0     0
      0     0     1     0     0
      0     1     0     0     0
      0     0     0     0     0
      0     0     0     0     0
```

[sub2ind](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html)
[linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511)